# For complex number $z$, if $|z| < r < 1$, then $|r - 1| < |z-1|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, proof-writing

> Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I claim that if $|z| < r < 1$, then $|r - 1| < |z-1|$

Is this claim true? I am trying to use this idea for a proof I am doing on absolute convergence of a complex series. I believe it to be true, but I don't want to use the result without justification (or even worse, use it if it is untrue).

My thought was basically that $r$ is closer to $1$ than $|z|$, so it ought to be true that $|r-1|$ is closer to $0$ than $|z-1|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true, by triangle inequality we have:

$$ |z-1|+|z| = |z-1|+|-z|\geq |z-1-z|= 1$$

so $$|z-1|\geq 1-|z| >1-r = |r-1|$$